# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'status' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to set boolean for status but i found the column 'status' cannot be null. What should I do? Below is the code I set for create user table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {


        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('role')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->string('address')->nullable();
        $table->string('city')->nullable();
        $table->string('postal_code')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table->boolean('status')->nullable($value = true);
```

Allows (by default) NULL values to be inserted into the column

Answer (score 1):

Set a default value for your `status` column

```
$table->boolean('status')->default(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check If you are inserting Data status has empty value for time of  insertion. 
  if you have send status value, please send me code of insertion...